# Minimize UWP application to system tray

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

Is there a way to minimize a windows 10 UWP application to the system tray. I've tried googling about this but all i can see is about wpf and windows forms.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What is it you're trying to accomplish? Do you want to open another application?

Comment: I'm trying to setup a command in cortana launching websites. example "Open Google Page" 

i'm using `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("https://google.com"));`  

but this methods requires the store app to be open in order to work. so im looking for a workaround that minimizes the store app to the system tray.

Comment: How would your app respond when running on a mobile device?

Comment: i'm currently targeting desktop family only. Isn't there a way? or is there another code i can use to launch website on default browser other than Launcher.LaunchUriAsync?

Comment: Vote for this issue on https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/12817866-minimize-uwp-application-to-system-tray

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible.

However, according to your description in the comments it is not needed, Cortana will launch your app. You probably have some other problems in handling arguments and finding which methods to override, but as there is nothing specific in your question about that, I can only guess...

Comment: See the win defender that can set it.

Comment: You probably have Windows UWP app that talks with Win32 app for that. With Desktop App Converter those things are possible now to be published on the Store and even be called UWP app.