# UWP: minimise a page from code

Tags: uwp

1. Make a new UWP project (on windows) and make a new page. Run the project, a blank form appears with a control box, I can press minimise and the page is minimised. Great!
2. I want to minimise the page from code. I put a button on the page. in the button handler I have:

   ```
   Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
       Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
   End Sub
   ```

But when I press is, the button disappears and the page just stays in view. How do I minimise the page?

Comment: what do you mean when you're talking about `minimize a page`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's duplicate [Minimize UWP application to system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310926/minimize-uwp-application-to-system-tray), and you can't minimize an application programatically in the UWP platform.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible by telling the UWP to enter suspended state, which minimises the window:

```
public IAsyncOperation<AppExecutionStateChangeResult> StartSuspendAsync()
```

See the microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startsuspendasync).